# How to exclude posts in a specific category?

Tags: php, wordpress

I display posts from the custom type of "event" records, display them under the heading, and below I do the same, but I need to exclude posts that have a heading that I have deduced above.
Here is my conclusion, how to exclude posts and rubrics with the "upcomingevents" ?

```html
<?php $wp_queryy = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'event','posts_per_page'=>'9','paged'=>$paged));
     if ($wp_queryy->have_posts()) : while ($wp_queryy->have_posts()) : $wp_queryy->the_post();?>

  <div class="top-event-block">
   <div class="upcoming-data"><?php echo get_the_date("M j, Y");?></div>
   <div class="upcoming-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
   <div class="upcoming-exp"><?php the_excerpt();?></div>
   <div class="upcoming-read-more"><a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a></div>
  </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I tried to insert into the query:

'cat' => '-28'

'cat' => '-upcomingevents'

'exclude_category' => '28'

'exclude_category' => 'upcomingevents'

'category__not_in' => array (28)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using custom post type, your arguments will not work. You  need to write the taxonomy query for it. Following code may help you, just add you taxnomoy name [ like : product_category ]

```
<?php 
            $args['post_type']='event';
            $args['posts_per_page']=9;
            $args['paged']=$paged;
            $args['tax_query'] = array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'event-category', //replace with your taxonomy name
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'upcomingevents',
                    'include_children' => true,
                    'operator' => 'NOT_IN'
                )
            );
            $wp_queryy = new WP_Query($args);
                    if ($wp_queryy->have_posts()) : while ($wp_queryy->have_posts()) : $wp_queryy->the_post();?>

        <div class="top-event-block">
            <div class="upcoming-data"><?php echo get_the_date("M j, Y");?></div>
            <div class="upcoming-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
            <div class="upcoming-exp"><?php the_excerpt();?></div>
            <div class="upcoming-read-more"><a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a></div>
        </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: The name of my taxonom is "event-category" alas, but it did not work

Comment: Please check I changed the code as per event-category